# Initializing CCSprite with objects in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to pass the score from my main layer to one of my CCSprite's that initialize depending on said score. When I initialize my CCSprite with this:

```
//Main Layer
Platform *platform = [[Platform alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:@"platform.png"] withScore:score];

//CCSprite Layer
-(id) initWithSpriteFrame:(CCSpriteFrame*)spriteFrame withScore:(int)initScore {
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I get a score with no CCSprite Texture;

Subsequently, when I initialize with this:

```
//Main Layer
Platform *platform = [[Platform alloc]initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:@"platform.png"]];
 [platform setScore:score];

//CCSprite Layer
@property (readwrite) int score;
@synthesize score;

-(id) init {
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I get a CCSprite Texture with no score(it's 0). What's a guy to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass along the sprite frame to super so in your first code example change it to this.

```
//CCSprite Layer
-(id) initWithSpriteFrame:(CCSpriteFrame*)spriteFrame withScore:(int)initScore {
    if( (self=[super initWithSpriteFrame:spriteFrame]) ) {
      ...
    }

    return self; //Make sure to return self!
}
```